# How can I find the cars I buy on my character's cell phone?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How can I find the cars I buy on my character's cell phone? What garage do I go to to get the car?

Answer (score 2):

The cars are spawned at your big garage (colorful garage icon on map) for every character. One should note that these cars are spawned only once so make sure you bring them back in one piece.

Answer (score 1):

The cars are sent to your garage within 24 hours of in game time. Your car can be found in the specific unique garages to each character.

If you bought the car with;

1. Fraklin-**Green garage** icon on the map,
2. Michael-**Blue garage** icon on the map,
3. Trevor-**Orange garage** icon on the map,

Answer (score 0):

The in-game help text told me that I can get them from the big garages that are available for each character. That would be the car park just south-east of Michaels house and the Groove Street Garage for Franklin.
I've only found the hangar on the airstrip near Sandy Shores for Trevor, which seems only to be used for airplanes (and the nearby helipad for helicopters).

I haven't bought any car yet so I can only tell this from the help text.

Answer (score 0):

Parking a car in a parking space can prevent it being towed/impounded + keeping track of the last location the car was parked will prevent loss of vehicle (and heart attack!) over loss of money and a sweet car.

---

In my case I assumed it would be at the impound lot when I finished a mission. I checked and it wasn't there  - only 2 random cars I had no intentions of keeping were there.

Luckily, I was able to track down the starting location of said mission via Internet searches and was able to find my car.

It was not parked in the space I left it in as parking in a space sometimes allows the cars to still be at the location instead of the impound. I assume this has worked in the past because the car is not illegally parked, resulting in a tow/impound.

Comment: Long story short, I just accidentally duplicated my car. After my break from single player, I spawned in my most recent quicksave- outside Franklin's purchased garage and drove another car out instead of my purchased via online and modded car mentioned above.   Curious of the impound lot since I disposed of the other two, sure enough my Obey 9F was in the impound. Also accompanied by the free Elegy RH8 I used previously. So, that makes it seem like there are more slots that the two to choose from and possibly four.